# Регулярные выражения, парсинг html

Tags: c#

здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста как из html кода вытащить ссылку которая идёт после src?

```
<div class="" id="captchaLevel">
            <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="captchaTable" dir="ltr" id="ask_captcha_content">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2" dir="ltr"><img alt="" class="image-captcha" height="40" src="http://ask.fm/simple_captcha/simple_captcha?simple_captcha_key=e567512416a27d7cae13e750f11d60f940227b13&amp;time=1430846324" width="100" /></td>
    <td><input class="field-captcha" id="captcha" maxlength="6" name="captcha" type="text" /><input id="captcha_key" name="captcha_key" type="hidden" value="e567512416a27d7cae13e750f11d60f940227b13" /></td>
    <td dir="ltr"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="captchaRefresh" onclick="Captcha.regenerate(&quot;#ask_captcha_content&quot;, &quot;/captcha/regenerate/ask_captcha&quot;); return false"><img alt="" class="border-none" height="16" src="/images/icons/captcha-reload.png" title="Перезагрузить" width="16" /></a></td>
  </tr>
```

т.е. нужна вот эта ссылка - `http://ask.fm/simple_captcha/simple_captcha?simple_captcha_key=e567512416a27d7cae13e750f11d60f940227b13&amp;time=1430846324`

Comment: По ссылке выше надо только заменить a.href на img.src.

Comment: **Никогда** не разбирайте HTML регулярными выражениями. Это очень нестабильный путь. Используйте CSS-селекторы, ну или на крайний случай XPath.